# DBContext fail No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'FolderNamespace'

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I have a large Project with an DBContext create with great EFCore PowerTool and mySql

On Debugging fails on load the EntitiesContext with

> System.InvalidOperationException: "No suitable constructor was found
> for entity type 'FolderNamespace'. The following constructors had
> parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
> cannot bind 'directorySeparator', 'path' in 'FolderNamespace(char
> directorySeparator, string path)'."

But i haven't a Entity like 'FolderNamespace'  ....

On create empty project with the same Database over EFCorePowerTool and Versions of Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql it runns correct!

Comment: Have you checked if `FolderNamespace` is used in any entity?

Comment: FolderNamespace is not used as entity. I have a Nuget from MimeKit Mail, but not used as entity ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer !

on a partial class from MimeKit Mail i've forget the

```
  [NotMapped]
  public ImapClient IC { get; set; }
```

to ignore on Entity Model...